# Have a problem with my jQuery Tabs

Tags: php, jquery

I have a jQuery based tabs which i got from some blog.So now when you click on the Tab,the respective content is loaded.

The content in each tab is quite huge and that is why i want to float the tabs on the right side of the screen.So how do i do that.

Here is the tabs which I'm talking about. http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not use jquery ui for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand what you are asking.
Do you want the tabs to be aligned to the right, that can be arrange by CSS or do you want them to hang on to the right side of the BOX, like a real life folder with separators?
Please explain with more detail what you want and how you have your tabs set up.

Comment: I want the tabs to flaot on the right of the Browser window.So that it slides with him.

Comment: that changes a lot. i dont think it can be explained right a way.
Use absolute positioning for the tabs and change the way they behave with the left border instead of the bottom border.  Using CSS, you can position the tabs, but maybe you need to calculate where they go before.  Do you have experience with Jquery or javascript?

Comment: No not  really,But i don't want to shift the tabs ..I want to replicate and make a copy of it on the side.

Comment: Let me see if I understood. You have tabs on top, and the same tabs on the right side, so when you scroll down because you have a large text you are still able to change to other content with the tabs on the right side. If it is like that you have to use absolute positioning for those tabs. In html the behavior of something vertical and horizontal changes a lot so. It is not as simple as to move a few lines of code. Create a div, with the tabs, us a list for those tab, configure them with css so the list vertical and look they way you want them. Use CSS absolute position.

Comment: Your exactly right on what to do,But i don't know how to do .. xD

Comment: Do you want me to right the code for you? Why dont you start with something after that we can give you directions.  that is why i asked if you know anything about jquery or CSS. Let me google stuff for you,
http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/517320.aspx